# How to mount disc images privately in OS X

Tags: macos, mount, disk-image

If I understand it correctly, the devices mounted in Mac OS under /Volumes are available to all users of the system.

This includes not only the internal hard drive, but also all external media, AFP shares, and mounted disc image files.

In a multi-user system, this poses a privacy problem. In our case, only one user should have access to a mounted disc image file.

[This article](https://www.cnet.com/tech/computing/mount-network-shares-privately-in-os-x/) explains how to assign the mount point for AFP and SMB volumes to a single user. This makes the volume invisible to all other users.

Can anyone help me out with the mount command for a disc image file?

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on using the **mount** command then please have a look at this [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147697/is-there-a-way-to-mount-a-disk-directly-to-a-specific-folder)!

Otherwise, **hdiutil** is very much your friend here.

Step 1:  Make a custom mount point for all your mounting needs, and make it accessible only to you.

```
mkdir ~/mnt
chmod 700 ~/mnt
```

Step 2:  "Mount" your disk images using the hdiutil, but leverage the *mount root* option and point it to your newly minted mount root.

```
hdiutil attach -mountroot ~/mnt /path/to/diskimage.dmg
```

If you execute `mount` with no arguments it will show you all mounted file systems and their mount points.  The catch here is that any user on the system can see this information (file names and mount paths).

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!